# Visual Studio debugging stop immediately on file upload in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I'm trying to get into .NET Core MVC using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

I tried to follow a fairly simple example from Microsofts own [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2). After setting up the code, I have the template project that they give you with MVC. So on the "About" page I have the following controller class `AboutController.cs` with the method found on Microsofts website:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
    string filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    if (files.Count > 0)
    {
        IFormFile file = files[0];
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

The only "big" difference is that I return the view, not an "Ok" because I'm not really interested in that. I want to modify the view I'm looking at not go to a completely new view (maybe I'm misunderstanding how MVC works?).

Now my HTML looks like this:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="About" asp-action="Post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>Upload one image using this form:</p>
            <input type="file" name="files">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This produces the form, also as seen in their documentation linked earlier. When I click the "Browse" button to find a picture, it works fine and when I click "Open" so I can upload it, the Visual Studio debugger stops running immediately. No error anywhere that I can see.

Any idea what causes this behaviour?

**Update 1**

It appears that just calling return View(); exhibits the same behaviour and Nuget says it's AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.1

**Update 2**

Turns out the debugger does not work in this particular instance with the browser called "Brave" which is a chromium browser that I use (which If forgot to mention)

Comment: What if you just have `return View();` in the method, without anything else. What does it do? Might also be interesting to add the version of ASP.NET Core being used.

Comment: It appears that just calling return View(); exhibits the same behaviour and Nuget says it's AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.1

Comment: Check the event viewer on yoru machine. I'm guessing something .Net is crashing. What type of hosting are you using when debugging, IIS, IIS Express, Kestrel?

Comment: Using IIS Express that Visual Studio set up itself when debugging. Where specifically in the Event Viewer should I look?

Comment: Application or system logs. I presume your using windows. I'd expect a critical error or something in there.

Comment: just tried the code at Microsoft and your code as well, both worked as expected. Try to empty your temp folder then upload

Comment: I think it is a browser issue as mentioned here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/261622/dotnetexe-crashes-when-upload-files-use-debug-mode.html and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/556910/uploading-file-in-mvc-project-under-debug-forces-p.html. Have you tried with other browsers to see if this behavior is also happening there?

Comment: We're going to need a [mcve] here

Comment: @RahulSharma I didn't really think about trying other browsers. That's my fault. But it worked in edge so it's clearly a browser problem then. Thank you. You could make it an answer to get the bounty once it runs out :)

I was using Brave.

Comment: this saved me. In edge works fine.... it is weird since i do not understand the relationship between the requesting client (brave) and the http server (webapi), why would VS care the process that started the http call? As far as I understand, VS debugger shouldnt be "attached" to that specific process at all. For all the debugger knows, the call could have originated from another computer via a tcp port...!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This behavior in specific has been attributed to a browser problem and not Visual Studio in general. As per [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/261622/dotnetexe-crashes-when-upload-files-use-debug-mode.html) article and [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/556910/uploading-file-in-mvc-project-under-debug-forces-p.html) article, this behavior was generally observed when using browsers like Brave in this case and Yandex. Sometimes even Chrome shows this behavior but it is not consistent (at least that is what I have observed).

A possible solution would be changing your browser type to use ideal browsers like Chrome, Firefox or Edge.

As pointed out in the comments for users using `Brave` browser:

> Turning the Shields off(down) stops the crashing. You can do
> this by clicking the shield icon to the right of the URL.

Comment: I had this problem today with Edge 83.0.478.44. but it work fine with firefox

Comment: Thanks, I had this problem while using Brave browser, but disappeared when I used Opera.

Comment: I have this problem on Brave Browser with .Net Core 3.1 and VS 2019. Thanks

Comment: Holy cow thank you - this was driving me nuts for hours!! /headdesk it was just the browser. Issue was w/Brave - fixed by moving (back) to Chrome. Thank you.

Comment: Alternative solution.  I had this problem with Brave. Turning the Shields off(down) stops the crashing for me.   You can do this by clicking the shield icon to the right of the URL.    I also have had brave issues and authentication into MS PowerPlatform (make and admin areas), again turning shields off solves the issues.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me.. to figure out the issue..

Comment: this saved me. In edge works fine.... it is weird since i do not understand the relationship between the requesting client (brave) and the http server (webapi), why would VS care the process that started the http call? As far as I understand, VS debugger shouldnt be "attached" to that specific process at all. For all the debugger knows, the call could have originated from another computer via a tcp port...!

Comment: I've been using Brave for over a year now and have not had this issue at all. All of a sudden yesterday this started happening and I have shields turned off. So frustrating.

Comment: I happend also in my chrome browser, but when I opened a second chrome instance it worked.

Comment: Your answer saved my day, after I already had lost my entire night burning the few neurons I have trying to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Shields down does not work for me, iisexpress crashes immediately when file is selected

Comment: @JoshStodola Try changing your browser. The shield option in `Brave` was one of the suggestion in the comments.