# is there any solution for visual studio debuger bugs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have asp.net core3 project, when i run project in debug mode in visual studio 2019 and click on browse button of a file uploader, debug mode will close and IIS go off.
my visual studio is up to date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio debugging stop immediately on file upload in mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023683/visual-studio-debugging-stop-immediately-on-file-upload-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58059150/14129713) stackoverflow question.

A possible solution is to use Firefox, chrome or edge. Please refer to the question once.