# ASP.NET MVC app shuts down when i try uploading files

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form in my asp.net web app, which sends files uploaded by the user

```html
<form method="post" asp-action="@((Model != null) ? "Update" : "Upload")" asp-controller="Materials" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="cat" type="hidden" name="cat" />
        <input id="subcat" type="hidden" name="subcat" />
        <input type="file" name="file" max="1" title="@((Model != null) ? "Обновить" : "Загрузить")"/><br />
        <input type="file" name="images" multiple title="Загрузить картинки"/><br />
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" /><br />
        <textarea id="desc" name="description" maxlength="199" ></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Сохранить"/>
</form>
```

There is one input for a file, and one input for image files, but as soon as I input any files the app just.... shuts down

Here is the method from the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file, IFormFileCollection images, string name, string description, string cat, string subcat)
{
    FileUploadManager f = new FileUploadManager(environment.WebRootPath + '/');
    f.Upload(file,images, name, description, cat + "-" + subcat);
    return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Material"));
}
```

the browser does not shut down, the app itself in the VS does, and without any exceptions, it just stops debugger as soon as files contact with HTML
also, I am using Yandex browser

Comment: Maybe you have a exception. If you attach the debugger you get a exception in the Upload?

Comment: What do you mean "shuts down"? This is a web app so by shut down do you mean the browser tab just closes or the entire browser just closes or visual studio closes or...

Comment: It could be a browser problem. You can find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58059150/1807452